# Converting Linq queries to Java 8

Tags: java, c#, linq

Im traslating a old enterprise App who uses C# with Linq queries to Java 8. I have some of those queries who I'm not able to reproduce using Lambdas as I dont know how C# works with those.
For example, in this Linq:

```
from register in registers
                               group register by register.muleID into groups
                               select new Petition
                               {
                                   Data = new PetitionData
                                   {
                                       UUID = groups.Key
                                   },
                                   Registers = groups.ToList<AuditRegister>()
                               }).ToList<Petition>()
```

I undestand this as a GroupingBy on Java 8 Lambda, but what's the "select new PetitionData" inside of the query? I don't know how to code it in Java.
I have this at this moment:

```
Map<String, List<AuditRegister>> groupByMuleId =
            registers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AuditRegister::getMuleID));
```

Thank you and regards!

Comment: It just means that for every elements returned by the query before this point, you return instead a new instance of the Petition class; and in the curly braces, you set its properties one by one, separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` LINQ operation is similar to the `map` method of `Stream` in Java. They both transform each element of the sequence into something else.

`collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AuditRegister::getMuleID))` returns a `Map<String, List<AuditRegister>>` as you know. But the `groups` variable in the C# version is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, AuditRegister>>`. They are quite different data structures.

What you need is the `entrySet` method of `Map`. It turns the map into a `Set<Map.Entry<String, List<AuditRegister>>>`. Now, this data structure is more similar to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, AuditRegister>>`. This means that you can create a stream from the return value of `entry`, call `map`, and transform each element into a `Petition`.

`groups.Key` is simply `x.getKey()`, `groups.ToList()` is simply `x.getValue()`. It should be easy.

I suggest you to create a separate method to pass into the `map` method:

```
// you can probably came up with a more meaningful name
public static Petition mapEntryToPetition(Map.Entry<String, List<AuditRegister>> entry) {
    Petition petition = new Petition();
    PetitionData data = new PetitionData();
    data.setUUID(entry.getKey());
    petition.setData(data);
    petition.setRegisters(entry.getValue());
   return petition;
}
```